# Printing integers in the ascending order recursively

Tags: java, recursion, methods, printing

Today, I have taken an exam, and there was a question:

Write a method which prints integer numbers in the **ascending** order **recursively** from 1 to n:

```
public class PrintIntegersAscendingOrder {

    static int counter = 0;
    public static void PrintIntegersAscendingOrder (int n)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {

            System.out.printf("%d\n", ++counter);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("%d ", ++counter);
            PrintIntegersAscendingOrder(n-1);
        }

    }
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        PrintIntegersAscendingOrder(5);
    }
}
```

Although this method worked now, the initial question didn't ask for the class definition, but the method. There, I couldn't be able to fit counter (I have written counter inside the if on the paper, but it gives an error in the program). How can I write the method precisely and correctly without counter variable?

Comment: the counter defeats the purpose of recursion here

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```java
public class IntegerAscendingOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        printIntegersAscendingOrder(n);
    }

    private static void printIntegersAscendingOrder(int i) {
        if (i < 1) {
            return;
        }

        printIntegersAscendingOrder(i-1);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

You don't need the counter variable in the class, using recursion you can limit the method call within the method itself.

Notice the `if (i < 1) {return;}` line, this will terminate the recursive method call(s).

This article should help you [Getting started with recursion](https://medium.com/@daniel.oliver.king/getting-started-with-recursion-f89f57c5b60e)

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void printIntegersAscendingOrder(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return;
        }
        printIntegersAscendingOrder(n - 1);
        System.out.printf("%d ", n);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printIntegersAscendingOrder(5);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

As @RobOhRob has already pointed out, the counter defeats the purpose of recursion in your code. When you are calling a function recursively, you need to analyse three important things:

1. When to stop the recursive call
2. Processing before making the recursive call
3. Processing before making the recursive call

Since you are already decreasing the parameter by `1` and passing it to the method to call it recursively, you can simply make use of this parameter instead of creating an additional variable (e.g. `counter`).

Comment: Please mention what was wrong in the code and how this solutions helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have defined in your class a method `PrintIntegersAscendingOrder` having the same name of the class `PrintIntegersAscendingOrder` containing it. This is an error that can be avoided for example renaming the including class to `PrintIntegers`. Below the code of class without the error and with the recursive method:

```
public class PrintIntegers {
    public static void PrintIntegersAscendingOrder(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            PrintIntegersAscendingOrder(n - 1);
            System.out.printf("%d\n", n);   
        }
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        PrintIntegersAscendingOrder(5);
    }
}
```